# White spaces are required between publicId and systemId while parsing KML document

Tags: java, parsing, kml, sax

I get this error while I try to parse a KML document:

```
com.bmw.cockpitm.business.backend.spec.ImportException: Error parsing KML data
at com.bmw.cockpitm.data.importers.riskmanagement.SimpleKmlDataImporter.importData(SimpleKmlDataImporter.java:120)
at com.bmw.cockpitm.jobs.ImportRiskEventsJob.execute(ImportRiskEventsJob.java:105)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:223)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 50; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
at com.bmw.cockpitm.data.importers.riskmanagement.SimpleKmlDataImporter.loadEventsData(SimpleKmlDataImporter.java:261)
at com.bmw.cockpitm.data.importers.riskmanagement.SimpleKmlDataImporter.importData(SimpleKmlDataImporter.java:100)
... 3 more
```

The KML document can be found [here](http://www.gdacs.org/kml.aspx?profile=ARCHIVE&eventtype=TC&from=2016-08-01T14:00:03Z) .

Most probably there is some error in the formating of the kml file, but I don't know where and what it is. Any help is welcomed.

Part of the KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<description>
    The Global Disaster Alert and Coordination System provides near real-time alerts about natural disasters around the world and tools to facilitate response coordination, including news, maps and V. OSOCC. GDACS is a joint initiative of the European Commission and the United Nations.
</description>
<name>Global Disaster Alert and Coordination system</name>
<Folder>
<name><![CDATA[ Tropical Cyclone HOWARD-16]]></name>
<Placemark id='TC_1000281'>
    <name>Green Alert for  Tropical Cyclone HOWARD-16 </name>
    <extendeddata>
        <data name="eventtype">
            <value>TC</value>
        </data>
        <data name = "eventid" >
            <value>1000281</value>
        </data >
        <data name="episodeid">
            <value>8</value>
        </data>
    </extendeddata>
    <snippet></snippet>
```

Comment: Please put the relevant sections of your KML file into the question, instead of as a link

Comment: That concerns a `<DOCTYPE ...>`. I did not see one in the kml, so maybe somewhere else.

Comment: @JoopEggen indeed there is no `<DOCTYPE ...>`, but the error happens on this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample KML document is not a valid KML document. It has numerous errors which can cause various parsing errors. However, it is a well-formed XML document in that the start and end tags match and attributes are quoted.

Three types of errors are described as follows:

### 1. Typos

First type of error is using a wrong element name. KML elements are case sensitive. Using the wrong element will often have those elements ignored in Google Earth. XML parsers may or may not ignore these errors.

```
Example: `<extendeddata>` element must be renamed with `<ExtendedData>`.
```

### 2. Out of order elements

Next type of errors result from out of order elements. KML 2.2 has a strict order of elements and elements should appear in the correct sequence. This is probably the most common error found in KML files.

Example:

```
   <Document>
    <description>The Global Disaster Alert...</description>
    <name>Global Disaster Alert and Coordination system</name>
```

The `<name>` field must be followed by the `<description>` element.

### 3. Missing altitudeMode but specifying an altitude

LineString for example has an altitude component (e.g. 30 meters) but the [altitudeMode](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#altitudemode) is missing so it is assumed *clampToGround* by default and altitude is ignored. If want the lines to appear off the ground then must specify *altitudeMode* with value of either absolute or relativeToGround.

```xml
<LineString>
     <extrude>0</extrude>
     <coordinates>
       123.5,16.483,30 123.5814,16.491,30 ...
     </coordinates>
</LineString>
```

#### Recommendations

Must first validate the KML document using validator such as [KML Validator](http://www.kmlvalidator.com/home.htm) or [Feed Validator](http://www.feedvalidator.org/). There is also a command-line [XML Validator](https://github.com/docjason/XmlValidate) tool that can validate any size KML or KMZ file. Then fix the validation errors.

Alternatively, you may want to disable schema and/or validation checking in the SAX parser.